# Is travel to the Schengen visa issuing country mandatory?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Is it necessary to visit the issuing country of a Schengen visa before visiting any other country? I applied for a visa at the French embassy but before making the trip, I have changed my mind and want to visit Italy now. Do I need to visit France before going to Italy since the visa was obtained based on an itinerary to France?

Also, could it lead to problems if I do not go to the issuing country (ie: France) at all?

I am quite confused about this. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not neccessary, but if France is not your main destination, you do open for speculation on whether your visa was obtained fraudulently, and if some immigration officer decides that to be the case, your visa will be cancelled.

You should contact the italian embassy in your country. They might say you should just go in which case you should just make sure to bring documentation of that.

There are also many related questions on this site (check the list on the right, there's probably more than will be displayed there at first, but clicking one will give a new list) and some of the answers to those might contain other helpful advice.

Comment: It's more than "open for speculation" - it is forbidden to use the visa for a purpose significantly different from what you requested.

Comment: @ugoren no it isn't.  It's forbidden to lie about your plans when you apply for a visa.  But a legitimate change of plans is not forbidden.  Whether a given change in plans is legitimate or the result of fraud is indeed open to speculation.